# Remove publickey from ssh login

Tags: linux, authentication, ssh, passwords

I'm trying to connect to an embedded board of mine through ssh. But upon trying to connect through `ssh -v -l root user@xx.xx.xx.xx`, I get a series of debug comments:

> dico@lithya:~$ sudo ssh -v -l root dico@foxboard2
>
> OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
>
> debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
>
> debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 22: Applying options for *
>
> debug1: Connecting to foxboard2 [10.251.145.180] port 22.
>
> debug1: Connection established.
>
> debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
>
> debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
>
> debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
>
> debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
>
> debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
>
> debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
>
> debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
>
> debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6
>
> debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6 pat OpenSSH*
>
> debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
>
> debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
>   debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
>
> debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
>
> debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
>
> debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
>
> debug1: Server host key: RSA 18:14:33:1e:88:5f:ad:13:78:9f:36:10:b9:d2:27:e4
>
> debug1: Host 'foxboard2' is known and matches the RSA host key.
>
> debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
>
> debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
>
> debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
>
> debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
>
> debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
>
> debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
>
> debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
>
> debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
>
> debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
>
> debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
>
> Permission denied (publickey,password).

The connection is being established through port 22 so that isn't the problem. So, clearly there is a problem with public/private key authentication. Therefore, how can I make sure that the private/public keys through both my machine and the board are in sync? Or better yet, how do I solve this issue or completely remove any keys?

**UPDATE**

I've tried to connect to the board by specifying no public key authentication by `ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no dico@foxboard2`, but now it's asking me for a password. I've checked the [site](http://www.acmesystems.it/ssh) but the password I type is incorrect. How can I remove a password request?

Comment: It's attempting authentication with your public key, against root's private key and is failing. To fix this problem, the contents of your ~/.ssh.id_rsa.pub file needs to be appended to /root/.ssh/authorized_keys on the server you're trying to connect to. Doing this requires that you already have some way to connect as root or can have someone do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy your public key to the server using:

```
ssh-copy-id user@xx.xx.xx.xx
```

It is always better to use keys than passwords.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I mentioned in the update that I removed public key authentication. But now I get a password request. In any case, I can't at all connect to the board not even to copy the id. When I type the `ssh-copy-id user@xx.xx.xx.xx`, I get: `/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: No identities found`.

Comment: If you don't have a working key OR a password, you are pretty much out of luck. :(

Comment: But why would it ask me for either when I've disabled public key authentication and I've never set a password. Is there a way to remove the latter?

Comment: Remember that PubkeyAuthentication=no is on the client side, not the server side. The board is a seperate computer, so you cannot change any configuration there without actually logging in.

Comment: Oh I see. But what is this error: `/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: No identities found`? Because if I can't send the board anything nor can I connect, is there pretty much nothing I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: You can use ssh-copy-id -i <path to id file> to point it to /root/.ssh/id_rsa or whereever your key is. However, ssh-copy-id will ask you for a password to copy the file.

Comment: Yeah the whole problem to the connection lies within this password request. Any idea how I can disable the password on the board?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `~/.ssh` directory is set to mode 700 (`chmod 700 ~/.ssh`) and your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is set to mode 600 (`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`).

In your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file set `PasswordAuthentication no` to turn off password logins.